# Rational way to move text to parent <ul> into new <span>?

Tags: javascript, dom

Recieving an Html tree with depth=2 from WordPress I need to move child's textContent to parent, even into new  at the end.

How can `appendChild()` be applied here correctly?

HTML tree (before)

```
<ul id="cities">
  <li><a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="">.1.</span></a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="">.1.2.</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

HTML tree (expecting)

```
<ul id="cities">
    <li><a href="">.1.<span class="popup">.1.2.</span></a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

JS

```
const suba = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu a');
const ct = document.querySelectorAll('#cities > li').length;
var init = document.querySelectorAll('#cities > li > a');
var ap = document.createElement('span');   appendix.className = 'popup';

for (var i=0; i < ct; i++) {
    ap.appendChild(document.createTextNode(suba[i].textContent);
    init[i].appendChild(ap[i]);
}
```

Actually I can't imagine anything better as I'm begining at JavaScript. The line `init[i].appendChild(ap[i])` has error.

If I erase index from argument, like line has changed to `init[i].appendChild(ap)` new Span will be added correctly, but only to the last parent node with textContent as long string of children.

Comment: `ap` is a span element? why do you have `ap[i]` instead of just `ap`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object

Comment: @xec if I erase array index, the code will append whole array as text to the last element of parent tree. Resuming, I need to append each child to each parent

Comment: but it's not an array, its a span element - right?

Comment: Oh yes, <span> is added correctly only to the last parent node. It's textContent is like all child elements had been put in one string

Comment: Hey, I just purged double appendChild and corrected the loop so now it works as text, without adding Span:
```for (i = 0; i < ct; i++) {
    ap[i]= document.createTextNode(suba[i].textContent);
    init[i].appendChild(ap[i]);
}```

Answer (score 0):

If we create a text node like:

```
var foo = document.createTextNode('abc');
```

and then check the value of `foo[0]`, we will see that the value is `undefined`. This means that your code passed `undefined` to the `appendChild` `function`, which resulted in the error you have pasted into the comment section. You have found a hack which technically solves the problem, but that assigns the sensible value into `ap[i]` in order to use it. But this is unnecessary. This simplified code is elegant and should work:

```
for (var i=0; i < ct; i++) {
    init[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode(suba[i].textContent);
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Lajos-arpad, I can't refer your answer as resulting, cause I've already published it in comment higher.